What timezone are Electrum's dates & times in? UTC?
What timezone are Electrum's dates & times in?
This answer to the question "Are time, timereceived and blocktime in UTC?" says:

All timestamps are in UNIX format, that is: the number of seconds since januari 1st 1970, 0:00 UTC.

Is this true of Electrum's dates & times, too?

Are you asking about the Electrum GUI, or some kind of RPC/command-linr interface? I'm not familiar with Electrum, but for a GUI I cannot imagine it is anything else than your computer's local timezone.

@PieterWuille Yes, the GUI.

What do the dates look like?
